# NoClassDefFoundError when using Ant to build and sign APK containing libraries

Tags: android, ant, jar

I'm having an issue while launching an APK that has been built and signed through Ant.

My project includes a library. This library is also a[image]

My project builds fine, but when I launch it, the app crashes with a NoClassDefFoundError.

I thought this error could be avoided by adding my library (here this is the library "SEMobile") "semobile.jar" into the "libs" folder of my project, but the result is exactly the same :

It builds and signs fine, but when I launch my application, it still crashes with a NoClassDefFoundError.

The stack trace of the crash is :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: fr.turbosa.turbosuite.releves.ReleveFragment
        at fr.turbosa.turbosuite.demarrage.FragmentMain.onCreate(FragmentMain.java:94)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2354)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
```

My project uses ActionBarSherlock, and it is added as a library project. The activity `ReleveFragment` is an extension of a `SherlockFragment`. Should I add my ActionBarSherlock jar file to my libs folder as well?

Comment: Try to `clean` and `restart eclipse`. Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to an external library used by my fragment (a jar file in a defined folder).

Setting this jar file into the "libs" library corrected that problem.